# Why is this program's output unexpected?

Tags: c++, eclipse

The following code when executed in eclipse, running on Ubuntu and compiled using g++ compiler, provides unexpected results.

## code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    unsigned int a=5555;
    std::cout << (unsigned int)(((char*)&a)[0]) <<  "\n";
    std::cout << (unsigned int)(((char*)&a)[1]) <<  "\n";
    std::cout << (unsigned int)(((char*)&a)[2]) <<  "\n";
    std::cout << (unsigned int)(((char*)&a)[3]) <<  "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to treat the variable `a` as an array of integers each of one byte size. When I execute the program, this is what I get as output:

## output:

```
4294967219
21
0
0
```

## question:

Why is the first value displayed so large (here `int` is of size 32 bits or 4 bytes). So each of the output values should obviously be no greater than 255 right? And why are the last three values zero? Or why I am getting the wrong result?

**I also got the same result when tested in code::blocks, running the same compiler.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of sign-extension. Let's look at your `unsigned int a` in memory:

```
b3 15 00 00
```

When you cast the first byte from a `signed char` to an `unsigned int`, the cast from `char` to `int` happens before the conversion from `signed` to `unsigned`, and therefore, the sign bit is extended, and the result (`0xffffffb3`) is what you see on your first line.

Try casting to an `unsigned char *` instead of a `char *`.

Answer (score 6):

This because `char` is a signed integer type.

Decimal 5555 is hexadecimal `0x15b3`.

The `0xb3` byte, when sign-extended to a `signed int`, becomes `0xffffffb3`.

`0xffffffb3` interpreted as an `unsigned int` is 4294967219 in decimal.